# .htaccess: combine useragent and logged in restrictions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, user-agent

I have a Wordpress website and I would like to give certain `useragents` unlimited access to my files. I've done this by putting a .htaccess in my uploads directory, with the following content:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*via docs.google.com/viewer.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*WordPress.* search_robot

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from env=search_robot
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png)$">
Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch “\.(docx|doc|pdf|rtf)$”>
Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from env=search_robot
</FilesMatch>
```

Now, for all other user agents, I would like to restrict access to logged in users. I know this type of restriction is possible using the following statements:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*uploads/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(docx|doc|pdf|rtf)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Could you please help me to incorporate both, so that firstly the user agent is checked, and the two User-Agents are allowed unlimited access, but that for all other user agents only logged-in users are allowed access?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in the end:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(via\ docs.google.com/viewer|WordPress) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /wp-login.php?redirect_to=/$1 [NC,R,L]
```